# Getting information about a particular sidekiq worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq

I have spawned a few thousand workers in sidekiq in the low queue. But apart from these workers there are a lot of other workers in low and other queues as well. I have access to the sidekiq admin dashboard and can view the queues and the workers running in them. But i need to scroll a lot to find information about workers that im interested in.

Is there a way to get information just about the status of the instances of a particular worker that im interested in ?

Comment: have u though to use https://datatables.net/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Busy page is merely a reflection of the data available in the Workers API, you can roll your own report.

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/API#workers